# Creating a dataframe from different length subject response pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have several dictionaries with country, response pairs, like this:

```
survey_1: {'France': 'Not answered', 'Germany': 'No', 'UK':'Yes'}
survey_2: {'France': 'Yes', 'Germany': 'Not answered', 'USA':'Maybe'}
survey_3: {'China': 'Yes', 'Germany': 'Yes', 'United Arab Emirates':'Yes'}
```

The lengths differ and the countries in each differ fromt the others. I want to combine them into a single dataframe like this:

[image]

I am not sure how to do it, because of the different lengths of the dictionaries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting multiple dict to a single dict and then use `pd.DataFrame`

**Ex:**

```
data = {"survey_1": {'France': 'Not answered', 'Germany': 'No', 'UK':'Yes'},
"survey_2": {'France': 'Yes', 'Germany': 'Not answered', 'USA':'Maybe'},
"survey_3": {'China': 'Yes', 'Germany': 'Yes', 'United Arab Emirates':'Yes'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                          survey_1      survey_2 survey_3
France                Not answered           Yes      NaN
Germany                         No  Not answered      Yes
UK                             Yes           NaN      NaN
USA                            NaN         Maybe      NaN
China                          NaN           NaN      Yes
United Arab Emirates           NaN           NaN      Yes
```